# How to show a MenuItem from a custom Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, searchview

I have a `SearchView` in my `onCreateOptionsMenu()` that I hide using:

```
if(mState == 0){
    msearchMenuItem.setVisible(false);  
}
```

I want it to be true after I access a custom `Fragment` that is part of a `ViewPager` in:

```
setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible){
}
```

I understand that I cannot pass a reference of the `MenuItem` to my `Fragment` because the `ActionBar` is not a `layout`, and all of its process needs to be from the `MainActivity`.

My option was to change the value of `mState` from `setMenuVisibility()` in my `Fragment`, but It shows the `SearchView` after I interact with my `DrawerLayout`. If I don't touch the home button, it would never show the `SearchView`.

Now, what can I do to load it exactly when I am at the `Fragment`?

Comment: `msearchMenuItem.setVisible(false);` is this inside the method `setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible)` or inside `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`. If it is in the latter, it won't be called until the menu is touched. Probably that's why you are not seeing it until you touch menu. In that case you should move it to the former method `setMenuVisibility`. Try posting full code snippets instead of parts, you will get better and faster answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual answer is overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu()` from my `Fragment`. But first, I had to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in `onCreate()`, so the override could take effect.

Answer (score 0):

you create a callback to the activity that enables the menu option again when you are in the fragment.

See [Communicating with an Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity)

Answer (score 0):

> Now, what can I do to load it exactly when I am at the Fragment?

You can use the `setMenuVisibility()` callback from your Fragment's `onCreateView()` method.